# Newrelic support in Quarkus native container

Tags: newrelic, quarkus

Is it possible to use Newrelic monitoring in Quarkus native build?

When using quarkus java build it should be easily to integrate with Newrelic with standard Newrelic java agent but in Quarkus native - I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

This is not related to Quarkus but to Substrate VM (the VM that runs the native application, part of GraalVM).

You can use Newrelic with Quarkus on Hotspot VM, but you cannot use it on native mode because Substrate doesn't support JVMTI and Instrumentation that are used by the Newrelic agent, see [GraalVM LIMITATIONS](https://github.com/oracle/graal/blob/master/substratevm/LIMITATIONS.md).

If you are using GraalVM EE, the documentation site said it adds *Managed capabilities for native code* but I didn't tested it so you should see with the Oracle support.